# SwiftUI - How to get user's Memoji?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, memoji

I was wondering how I can get a user's Memoji with SwiftUI. Unfortunately, Apple's AvatarKit is private and can't be used in production apps.

So is there a way to get a Memoji sticker from the keyboard? I've tried looking at `.keyboardType` but it doesn't have any options for stickers/memoji.

I am basically wondering how I can get the Memoji to show up in the keyboard for a TextField in SwiftUI. I know you can do it outside of SwiftUI (by setting `allowsEditingTextAttributes` to `yes`).

Comment: Well if I could do it with SwiftUI that would be great. There's no way to set a SwiftUI TextField to accept a Memoji sticker?